# Cannot convert method group 'Read' to non-delegate type 'bool'

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I am trying to use `SqlDataReader` to check if a entry exists. If it exists, it will return the ID, else it will return false. When I try to compile, I'm getting the error "Cannot convert method group 'Read' to non-delegate type 'bool'. I have been following an example I found in VB, but it seems the translation may not be correct.

```
private string checkProfileExists()
{
    string strReturn = "False";
    string strSql = ("SELECT ID FROM tblInformation WHERE txtUsername=@UserName " + 
        "AND TrackingID=@TrackingID");
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WEM_PassWord_Reset"].
        ConnectionString;


    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, objConn);

    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackingID", txtTrackingID.Text);

    try
    {
        objConn.Open();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr.Read)
        {
            strReturn = rdr("ID").ToString;
        }
        else
        {
            strReturn = "False";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        objConn.Close();
        objCmd = null;
    }

    return strReturn;
}
```

Comment: You guys close questions for being too vague or too open but also for being too localized? Why would that be a problem? Looking to fix this issue has landed me on this question and it has helped me.

Answer (score 27):

When you see the phrase 'method group' in a C# error, one explanation to consider is that you have omitted the parentheses `()` from a method that takes no arguments. In this case, the method is `Read` on your `DataReader`.

When the compiler sees `Read` (with no parentheses), it thinks you are talking about the method itself, as if trying to assign it to a delegate, say. Whereas what you actually want to do is *invoke* the method - to do this, in C#, you must give the list of arguments (which in this case is empty), thus: `Read()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (rdr.Read())
{
    strReturn = rdr["ID"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Read is a method in the SqlDataReader class, which in this case doesn't take parameters

Comment: @Jhonny in C#, method invocations always require *parentheses*, even when they take no *parameters*

Comment: thank you for the help, now that I see it, it makes complete sense

Comment: Yes, but he clearly stated that this code snippet was a translation from VB. I thought it would be a good idea to expand a little on the explanation, not just point the finger on the error, cause the compiler already did that

Answer (score 3):

The () for method invocation of parameterless methods are not optional in C#. Without the parentheses the the expression identifies the method(group) and not its result value. This behavior makes the grammar much less ambiguous, especially for methods that return delegates.

The first reaction of a C# programmer when he sees "Cannot convert method group '...' to non-delegate type '...'" is usually "Oh I forgot my () for invocation".

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your source I highly recommend to use the using statement for both the SqlConnection AND the SqlDataReader.

If you do NOT Close the reader, the garbagecollection moment will decide when the reader finalizes. You can bring SqlServer DOWN when you do not know that.