# Implicit cast of Func<MyType> to MyType

Tags: c#, callback, implicit-conversion

Given the following class:

```
public class MyType
{
    public static implicit operator MyType(Func<MyType> wrapper) {
        return wrapper();
    }
}
```

From the implicit cast of `Func<MyType>` to `MyType`, I assumed the following would be possible:

```
public MyType MyTypeWrapper() {
    return new MyType();
}

public void MyTestMethod() {
    MyType m = MyTypeWrapper; // not a call!
}
```

However I'm getting:

> Cannot convert method group 'MyTypeWrapper' to non-delegate type 'Test.MyType'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Which, unfortunately for me, when searched for (*as I half expected*) resulted in [tons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730302/cannot-convert-method-group-tolist-to-non-delegate-type) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890323/cannot-convert-method-group-read-to-non-delegate-type-bool) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263731/cannot-convert-method-group-emisnull-to-non-delegate-type-bool-did-you-inte) to which the answer was:

> Hey, ya dun goofed; toss `()` on the end of `WhateverMethod`!

Now, as I'm typing this, I've noticed that an **explicit** cast does in fact compile:

```
MyType m = (MyType) MyTypeWrapper;
```

Why is it that I cannot implicitly cast a `Func<MyType>` to `MyType` as I've described?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're already using the built-in implicit conversion from *method group* to `Func<MyType>`.

The compiler won't do two implicit conversions at once.

Once you have an explicit cast to your class, the compiler knows to look for an implicit cast to any type that can be explicitly casted to your class.

Comment: Ah, I see. Any way to mitigate this compiler "feature"? (*I'm guessing "No"*)

Comment: @Bracketworks: No.  Method groups are a very unusual type of expression in that they don't have a type in and of themselves (like `null` and lambdas).

Comment: @Bracketworks It's not really feasible, even if they wanted to, as per my answer.  The compiler is looking for a conversion from one type to another, and when it does it looks for one conversion that does exactly that, not any conversion that goes to any type that has a conversion to the type you want.  That gets out of hand *really* quick for both the compiler, and also the programmer.  Imagine me having a mean class with a conversion from object to me and from me to object.  Now any assignment could possibly involve both operations running, allowing me to do all sorts of mean things.

Comment: Understandable, I guess I'll just have to invoke it in place :(

Comment: Just to clarify: the compiler *will* chain some implicit conversions. For example, if you have a user-defined implicit conversion from int to Frob then you get a conversion from short for free.  short --> int --> Frob. The conversions that are allowed are documented in section 6.3 of the spec, and method group conversions are deliberately left off that list.

Comment: @SLaks: You're welcome. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/04/16/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c.aspx for some analysis of this rule.

Answer (score 12):

This is unfortunate. I'm pretty sure you've found a compiler bug, and this section of the specification is extremely difficult to read.

Section 6.4.4 of the C# 4 specification explains why your implicit conversion is illegal.

The algorithm goes like this.  First look at the source type and target type. There is no source type because a method group has no type.  The target type is `MyType`. So search `MyType` for user-defined implicit conversions.  Now the question is: what is the *set of applicable user-defined operators ... that convert from a type encompassing S*?  `S` is the source type and we have already established that *there is no source type*. So this is already evidence that the conversion should fail. But even if the compiler for some reason decides that your `Func<MyType>` conversion is applicable, the rule is *a standard implicit conversion ... is performed*. **Method group conversions are deliberately not classified as standard conversions**.

So that's why it should be illegal.

Why then is the explicit cast legal?

There's no justification for that. This appears to be a bug.

This is unfortunate; many apologies for the error. I shall report it to my former colleagues; if they have an analysis which conflicts with mine, I'll update the answer.

UPDATE: My former colleagues inform me that the spec problem whereby the source expression is assumed to have a type will be addressed by a rewording in the next release of the spec. No word yet as to whether the explicit cast behavior is a bug.

Comment: I was slightly surprised that the explicit conversion worked.  Do you disagree with the last line of my answer? (I didn't look for it in the spec)

Comment: @SLaks: The compiler knows to look at `MyType` in the implicit case because it knows that this is the only possible target type of the implicit conversion. Contrast with this scenario: if you had an *explicit* user-defined conversion from Giraffe to Fruit and you explicitly cast a reference to Animal to type Banana then the compiler will search Animal, Banana and Fruit for conversion operators but not search Giraffe, so if the user-defined conversion is declared on Giraffe, you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm glad I tried the explicit cast then! Thanks for the update @EricLippert, looking forward to more info :)

Comment: If an expert in compiler design has trouble reading the spec, there's not much hope for us mere mortals.

Answer (score 1):

Because the C# compiler isn't able to convert `MyTypeWrapper` into a `Func<MyType>(MyTypeWrapper)`.  There's a difference between a method group and an actual delegate.

This compiles and runs fine:

```
MyType m = new Func<MyType>(MyTypeWrapper);
```

There is an implicit conversion from a method group to a delegate type that matches that group, and there is your user defined implicit conversion from that delegate to a type.  The general idea here is that the compiler is only going to use one implicit conversion in a row at a time.  When it has an A and needs a C it looks for conversions from A to C, not from A to any type B and from that type to C.  That algorithm goes from O(n) to O(n^2) (not to mention possibly being quite confusing for programmers).

The reason your code works when using an explicit cast to `MyType` is that you're no longer chaining implicit conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `MyTestMethod` MATCHES the signature of `Func<MyType>` but is NOT a `Func<MyType>`. Func has defined some implicit casts itself to allow you to assign such methods as Funcs, but you must explicitly cast for the signature to apply, because the compiler will not chain implicit casts together for you:

```
MyType m = (Func<MyType>)MyTypeWrapper; // not a call!
```